# Equilibrium point in a system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

Suppose we are given the following system:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = Ax(t) + g(x(t))
\end{equation}
We are given that the property $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\|g(x)\|}{\|x\|} = 0$. Now, I want to show the origin is an equilibrium point for this system.

My attempt:
Showing this is equivalent to showing $g(x) = 0$. If we use Taylor expansion:
\begin{equation}
g(x) = g(0) + g'(0)x + \frac{g''(0)}{2!}x^{2} + ...
\end{equation}
Then:
\begin{equation}
\frac{g(x)}{||x||} = \frac{g(0)}{||x||} + \frac{g'(0)}{||x||}x + \frac{g''(0)}{2!{||x||}}x^{2} + ...
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{||g(x)||}{||x||} \leq \frac{||g(0)||}{||x||} + \frac{||g'(0)||}{||x||}||x|| + \frac{||g''(0)||}{2!{||x||}}||x||^{2} + ...
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{||g(x)||}{||x||} \leq \lim_{x \to 0} \{ \frac{||g(0)||}{||x||} + \frac{||g'(0)||}{||x||}||x|| + \frac{||g''(0)||}{2!{||x||}}||x||^{2} + ...\}
\end{equation}

which leads to

\begin{equation}
0 \leq||g'(0)|| 
\end{equation}

which is not useful. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any conditions on the matrix $A$? Also, what makes you think that the statement you want to prove is true?

Comment: @KBS, $A$ is given as Hurwitz, but I did not see why this relevant. So that why I did not provide this information in the question. We know that the statement is true, just need to prove it.

Comment: Please always provide all the available information when posting something.

Comment: Without the full information you might solve the wrong task. $g(0)=0$ it trivial given the assumptions, so $x\equiv 0$ is a solution, thus the point $x=0$ an equilibrium. There might be a part of the task that asks if the full equation inherits the stability properties of $A$, that is, the reduced system $\dot x=Ax$.

Comment: @KBS, sorry i will keep that in mind.

Comment: @LutzLehmann actually we don't know $g(0) = 0$, how do you prove that?

Comment: @LutzLehmann there is also a part which asks about showing the linearized system at the origin is $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)$.

Comment: Per the given properties $g(x)=o(x)$, so indeed $g(0)=0$ is trivial to deduce, see the answer below. And from the same property follows that $g$ is super-linear, so does not contribute to the linearization.

Comment: @LutzLehmann what's wrong with Taylor expansion approach? I feel like I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: It is not known if $g$ is differentiable. Presumably it is continuous, probably also Lipschitz so that uniqueness theorems apply.

Comment: @LutzLehmann what's the relation between your statement and Taylor expansion?

Comment: If you don't have derivatives, there are no coefficients for the Taylor expansion. And even if at least $g\in C^1$, your conclusion should be $g(0)=g'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the following is what you want.

If you assume $\displaystyle \lim_{\left\|x \right\| \to 0}\dfrac{\left\|g(x) \right\|}{\left\|x \right\|}=0$ then

for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist a $\delta>0$ such that for $\left\|x \right\|<\delta$ we have:

$\dfrac{\left\|g(x) \right\|}{\left\|x \right\|}<\epsilon$. Taking $\epsilon=1$ we obtain $\left\|g(x) \right\|<\left\|x \right\|$ for $\left\|x \right\|<\delta$.

Thus, setting $x=0$ we obtain $g(x)=0$.

Comment: How do you know $\frac{||g(x)||}{||x||}$ always can be upper-bounded by some constant?

Comment: It is not globally upper bounded. It is bounded for$ ||x||<\delta$. But this is all we need I think!